# Apache karaf how to easily install bundle from Maven repo

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, karaf

I am trying out Karaf and installed some bundle X. This bundle X complains about a missing requirement: `Unresolved requirements ... osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.commons.httpclient)]`

Hence, I tried to provide the org.apache.commons.httpclient through `bundle:install mvn:commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1` which worked.

But, after trying to start the X again, I still get the same error message.

thanks!

Answer (score 7):

That jar is not a bundle, hence can't be deployed to karaf, it's just ignored.

Try

```
karaf@root>bundle:install -s mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-httpclient/3.1_7
```

Make it sure that your bundle has in their META-INF/MANIFEST.MF the osgi import declarations syntax. I assume that you use bndtools to generate the bundle.

Answer (score 4):

Agree with @Antonio, for third party libraries which are not OSGi bundles you can also try to install them with `wrap`:

```
bundle:install -s wrap:mvn:commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1
```

This will create a basic OSGi MANIFEST for the library...

You can find more info here: http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/creating-bundles.html

Comment: Your link is dead.